# Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bfgf5f6f11d50abb'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of issue? It is a .net core 1.1 application, I have seen several solutions for similar problems, but they did not seem to work.

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri)
 at System.Net.WebRequest.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
 at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
 at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
 at _6h.lt.Models.reg_class.<complete_payment>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Did you try to Clean/Rebuild your project ?

Answer (score 1):

removing this helped to solve the problem:

left click project file, then click edit some.csproj and then simply delete this and save the file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />
```

Comment: I am getting this error, but this package is not included.